# For convex cyclic hexagon $ABCDEF$, show $AC\cdot BD \cdot CE \cdot DF \cdot EA\cdot FB \geq 27\cdot AB\cdot BC\cdot CD \cdot DE\cdot EF\cdot FA$

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, polygons, geometric-inequalities

> Given a convex hexagon $ABCDEF$ inscribed in the circle, prove that
>   $$AC\cdot BD \cdot CE \cdot DF \cdot EA\cdot FB \;\geq\; 27\cdot AB\cdot BC\cdot CD \cdot DE\cdot EF\cdot FA$$

("$AC$" means the length of the segment with endpoints $A$ and $C$.)

What I did until now: bashing complex and making problem even harder!

Comment: Can you explain your notation? At first I though $AC$ might be the real valued length of the segment with endpoints $A$ and $C$, and $*$ might denote multiplication of real numbers, but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: I flagged this question as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513053 and deleted my answer here, since the other link has two answers, one being accepted and one being a repost of the answer I had given here.